# AVAudioPlayer resetting currently playing sound and playing it from beginning

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I'm having an issue using AVAudioPlayer where I want to reset a player if it's currently playing and have it play again.

I try the following with no luck:

The sound plays once but then the second time i select the button it stops the sound, the third time starts the sound up again.

```
//Stop the player and restart it
if (player.playing) {
    NSLog(@"Reset sound: %@", selectedSound);
    [player stop];
    [player play];
} else {
    NSLog(@"playSound: %@", selectedSound);
    [player play];      
}
```

I've also tried using player.currentTime = 0 which indicates that would reset the player, that didn't work, I also tried resetting currentTime = 0 and then calling play that didn't work.

```
//Stop the player and restart it
if (player.playing) {
    NSLog(@"Reset sound: %@", selectedSound);
    player.currentTime = 0;
    [player play];
} else {
    NSLog(@"playSound: %@", selectedSound);
    [player play];      
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For your situation I would try the following

```
//Pause the player and restart it
if (player.playing) {
    NSLog(@"Reset sound: %@", selectedSound);
    [player pause];
}

player.currentTime = 0;
[player play];
```

If you are going to immediately play the sound again, I would suggest pause instead of stop.  Calling stop "Stops playback and undoes the setup needed for playback."

Comment: FWIW, I've seen that just setting currentTime to zero is enough. With the method described here, I see the audio refusing to play after doing it a few times in quick succession.

Answer (score 4):

As indicated, if you want the sound to play again, you should avoid disabling the AVAudioPlayer instance with a stop but rather, just issue a reset of the position where it is playing. So, don't use stop() or pause() but as Plumenator mentioned, just issue .currentTime=0. So in your case, you would simply do:

```
if (player.isPlaying) { 
   player.currentTime = 0
} else {
   player.play()
}
```

Comment: Since you essentially duplicate Plenumenator's comment, could you expand your answer by adding a reference code sample?

Comment: Thanks, a good suggestion.  I've added the block so that it becomes more clear what Plumenator is suggesting :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Swift example:

```
player.currentTime = 0.0;
```